# How to catch "coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException" equivilant in Railo?

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling, railo, cfml

The following is done comparing Coldfusion 9.0.1 against Railo 4.0.2.002

I have the following (truncated) as the init for a cfc

```
component {
    public myComponent function init(
        required string inSetting1,
        required string inSetting2
    ) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

If I run the following, then it invokes correctly

```
objInstance = new myComponent(
    inSetting1 = 'xxx',
    inSetting2 = 'yyy'
);
```

However I am attempting to handle a misconfiguration requesting this object without all required arguments.  So far I have got the following

```
try {
    // inSetting2 is not defined == will cause error
    objInstance = new myComponent(
        inSetting1 = 'xxx'
    );
} catch (coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException e) {

    // This catches the error for CF 9.0.1

} catch (expression e) {

    // This catches the error for Railo 4.0.2
    debug(e); // get the error dump for stack trace below

}
```

So far in place of `expression` I have tried the following to no avail based off the opening `railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.defineArguments(UDFImpl.java:171)` from the stack trace (which is how I retrieved the specific type for CF9)

- railo
- railo.runtime
- railo.runtime.type
- railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl
- railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.defineArguments

Now while I could just do `catch (expression e)` or even `catch (any e)`, I would much rather be able to catch the specific errors for the simple reason that in some locations within the components which I am currently updating to work with Railo it has relied on being able to determine the reason for failure to be able to differentiate configuration errors (missing arguments) from deployment errors (missing template).

So, is anyone aware of a method by which I could make the above try/catch look specifically for an equivilant of `coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException` (or for that matter, a method by which I could check the required arguments prior to attempting to invoke/run the method(s) in question)

Edit : I forgot to include the stack trace.  Here is the Railo stack trace. I have also already tried the following in place of `expression`

```
 The parameter environment to function init is required but was not
 passed in. at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.defineArguments(UDFImpl.java:171):171 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:369):369 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:275):275
 at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:608):608 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1800):1800
 at
 railo.runtime.functions.other._CreateComponent.call(_CreateComponent.java:49):49
 at
 mso.dev_test315.mycomponenttest_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/myComponentTest.cfc:133):133
 at
 mso.dev_test315.mycomponenttest_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/myComponentTest.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:275):275
 at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:608):608 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1796):1796
 at railo.runtime.tag.Invoke.doComponent(Invoke.java:209):209 at
 railo.runtime.tag.Invoke.doEndTag(Invoke.java:182):182 at
 mxunit.framework.testcase_cfc$cf._2(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestCase.cfc:115):115
 at
 mxunit.framework.testcase_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestCase.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:275):275
 at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:608):608 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1800):1800
 at
 railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:749):749
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1521):1521
 at
 mxunit.framework.decorators.dataproviderdecorator_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/decorators/DataProviderDecorator.cfc:31):31
 at
 mxunit.framework.decorators.dataproviderdecorator_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/decorators/DataProviderDecorator.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781 at
 railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuiterunner_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuiteRunner.cfc:99):99
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuiterunner_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuiteRunner.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284 at
 railo.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.call(UndefinedImpl.java:774):774
 at
 railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuiterunner_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuiteRunner.cfc:52):52
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuiterunner_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuiteRunner.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781 at
 railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuite_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuite.cfc:131):131
 at
 mxunit.framework.testsuite_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/TestSuite.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781 at
 railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
 at
 mxunit.framework.remotefacade_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/RemoteFacade.cfc:76):76
 at
 mxunit.framework.remotefacade_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/mxunit/framework/RemoteFacade.cfc):-1
 at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371 at
 railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:498):498 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1789):1789 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentWrap.call(ComponentWrap.java:165):165 at
 railo.runtime.net.rpc.server.ComponentController._invoke(ComponentController.java:56):56
 at
 railo.runtime.net.rpc.server.ComponentController.invoke(ComponentController.java:34):34
 at __138.mxunit.framework.remotefacade_wrap.executeTestCase(Unknown
 Source):-1 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown
 Source):-1 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source):-1 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source):-1 at
 org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397):397
 at
 org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186):186
 at
 org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323):323
 at
 org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32):32
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118):118 at
 org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83):83 at
 org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454):454
 at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281):281
 at
 railo.runtime.net.rpc.server.RPCServer.doPost(RPCServer.java:312):312
 at
 railo.runtime.ComponentPage.callWebservice(ComponentPage.java:783):783
 at railo.runtime.ComponentPage.call(ComponentPage.java:155):155 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:801):801
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:753):753
 at
 railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:183):183
 at
 railo.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:18):18
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2255):2255
 at
 railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2222):2222
 at
 railo.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:310):310
 at railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:29):29 at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728):728 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305):305
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210):210
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222):222
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123):123
 at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472):472
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171):171
 at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99):99
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118):118
 at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407):407
 at
 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200):200
 at
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589):589
 at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310):310
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
 Source):-1 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source):-1
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source):-1
```

Comment: If you `cfdump` the error when you catch it I believe the stack trace will show you what you want.  Can you post the resulting stack trace here?

Comment: So when you catch the error in Railo, what is the value of e.type?

Comment: e.type is simply `expression`.  For clarity the above is from the myComponentTest.cfc which is the unit test, and the stack trace is from performing debug(e); on a `} catch (any e) {}`

Comment: I believe this is the spot in the Railo source, hopefully that sheds some light. https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/tag/TagUtil.java#L43

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as the message matches that indicated under ExpressionException which would make sense given the stack trace (https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/type/UDFImpl.java#L171) which is hardcoded to return a type as 'exception' (ExpressionException#22 `super(message,"expression");`) through the PageExceptionImpl class (https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/exp/PageExceptionImpl.java#L74), most unhelpful

Comment: I suggest [raising an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO) for this - there _should_ be a more precise exception type.

Comment: Simon, regarding your tag edits: cfscript is _part of_ cfml. Also, CFML is the term used when referring to both ColdFusion and Railo.

Comment: My apologies, my understanding was cfml related to the cf tags specifically rather than cfscript being a subset of cfml.  I understood that cfml/cfscript applied equally to CF/Railo though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler workaround than what you are currently using:

```
try
{
    // standard function call
}
catch (expression e)
{
    if ( NOT refind('The parameter \S+ to function \S+ is required but was not passed in',e.message) )
        rethrow;
}
```

Of course, this relies on the wording of the error message, so is somewhat brittle.

You could alternatively do a less precise but more flexible version, just checking for the keywords:

```
if ( NOT find('parameter',e.message) AND find('required',e.message) )
```

Comment: I had considered this however decided against it as it would not be compatible with CF as well as Railo, and so would still require the CF-specific error message to be implemented.

Comment: Huh? CF compatibility is easy: `if ( e.type EQ 'coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException' OR ... )`

Comment: Will select this as answer as it is the most suitable for the original question, albeit not suitable for my own purpose - in the end I stuck with my own solution below though.

Answer (score 0):

Solution currently being employed (unless a better solution is offered in the next few days) will be by use of a method as follows :

```
boolean function checkRequiredArguments(
    required inFunction,
    required struct inArguments
) {
    // This is intended to check the function for required arguments and ensure they are present in the struct
    var arrFunctionArguments = GetMetaData(arguments.inFunction).parameters;
    for (var thisArgument in arrFunctionArguments) {
        if (
            thisArgument.required // argument is required
            &&
            !IsDefined('arguments.inArguments.'&thisArgument.name) // but not defined
        ) {
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

This will return true if all required arguments are valid.  In context of the init argument of the component above, the following example code would ensure that all required arguments are at least defined in some form (some refinement would allow this to confirm types also)

```
objTest = CreateObject('myComponent');
stcArguments = {
    inSetting1 = 'XXX'
}
if ( checkRequiredArguments( inFunction = objTest.init , inArguments = stcArguments ) ) {
    objTest.init( argumentCollection=stcArguments );
} else {
    throw(type='MissingArguments');
}
```